# Regular Expression that don't much phrase but match word

Tags: java, regex

I would like to have a regular expression that would match the phrases "chocolate ice-cream", "vanilla ice-cream" or just "ice-cream" but not the phrase "no ice-cream". I am awful with regular expressions and so far I have something like this: `(!no\ice-cream)|(chocolate\sice-cream)|(vanilla\sice-cream)|(ice-cream)` but of course the last group also matches the word: ice-cream if the phrase: no ice-cream exists. Can someone help? Thanks.

Comment: Where are you going to use the expression? As the [regex tag info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) states, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a negative lookbehind as follows: `(!no\ice-cream)|(chocolate\sice-cream)|(vanilla\sice-cream)|((?<!no )ice-cream)`
Hope this helps.